# How to maximize $x^2-2bxy-7x+2y^2+133$?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Suppose you have some function $g_b(x,y)=x^2-2bxy-7x+2y^2+133$ where $b\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> How would you find the maximum of $g_b(x,y)$ on the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ x^2+3y^2\leq 16\}$?

---

My intuition suggests that I should factor the function such that for any $(x,y)$, it is easy to identify which ones are positive or negative (i.e. use the fact that $x^2\geq 0$).

However, I honestly don't know if that is the correct direction since I can't figure out how to factor this with $b$ unknown. I appreciate any guidance! Thank you!

Comment: Approaching this problem with Kuhn-Tucker optimization techniques or using Lagrangians may be helpful.

Comment: @kimchilover oops, that's my mistake. Just a typo!

Comment: It is hard to reason with the function: for $b=-2$, the maximum of $g_b(x,y)$ is attained when $x$ and $y$ are negative ([Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximise+x%5E2%2B4xy-7x%2B2y%5E2%2B133+when+x%5E2%2B3y%5E2%E2%89%A416)), even though it looks like the $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms dominate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $g_b(x, y)=a$

$x^2-2bxy-7x+2y^2+133=a$

Solve equation for x:

$x=(1/2)[2by+7 + \sqrt \Delta]$
$\Delta=(2by+7)^2-4(2y^2+133-a)=(4b^2-8)y^2+2by-483+4a$

Now x is maximum if $\Delta$ is maximum. For this take derivative of $\Delta$ equate it to zero and so on.